# Angular model doesn't update with space

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When an angular model is bound to an input, Angular doesn't seem to update the value if a space is added.  Even if the model is watched, the value still does not update.

I created a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vYLQk/8/) to demonstrate the issue.  Type a string, and notice the values in the bound spans update.  However, add a space to the end of the string and the value doesn't update.  Is there a way to force angular to watch for spaces as well?

The specific code is:

**View**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input data-ng-model="inputValue">
  <p>This value: ----<span data-ng-bind="inputValue"></span>----</p>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.inputValue = 'Superhero';
});
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to set `ngTrim` to false. By default Angular sets it to true, which trims white space in input boxes:

```
<input data-ng-model="inputValue" data-ng-trim="false" />
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vYLQk/9/

Docs: http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/docs/api/ng.directive:input.text

Comment: Thanks for that.  My actual problem is also a bit more advanced.  I'm trying to add the data-ng-trim attribute through a directive, but it doesn't seem to apply.  Are there any best practices or examples for that?